# Finding self-intersection in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, self-intersection, postgis-2.4

I've developed an query to find self-intersection points by using PostgreSQL 10 and PostGIS 2.4 database. The query took long time (aprx 90mins) to produce the result from 3,122 polygons. The query is:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ST_AsText((ST_DumpPoints(ST_Node( ST_ExteriorRing(geom)))).geom) pnt, id FROM "Table_Polygon" ) AA WHERE aa.pnt not in (SELECT DISTINCT ST_AsText((ST_DumpPoints( ST_ExteriorRing(geom))).geom) pnt FROM "Table_Polygon" )
```

The vertices returned from the two sub queries are 4,09,122 and 4,09,120 respectively. Only the additional two vertices from 1st the sub query will be result as self-intersection points

[image]

The result is:

[image]

Are there any alternative PostGIS functions which can be used to optimize this query to get the quick result from this huge volume of data?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you think about adding a where St_IsValid(geom) = False ?

This may avoid to look for geometry wich are valid and then doesn't have self intersection issue. 
If you have performance issues, be sure to use a spatial index like Gist also.

You can also look for some work-around with St_MakeValid.

Comment: Or perhaps https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValidReason.html or https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValidReason.html

Comment: in fact, `SELECT ST_MakeValid(geom) AS geom FROM <layer>;` should split self-intersecting polygons at their intersecting vertices. pedantic note: while obligatory for performance in general, a spatial index would make no difference with OPs query...

Comment: @Maximilien: Many thanks. It helps lot to reduce the computation speed.

Comment: For Line geometry, ST_IsValid is returning as true always. ST_IsSimple(geom) =false is working fine for line geometry